# Freeradius 3 can't find Auth-Type for pfSense OpenVPN Auth-Requests

Tags: active-directory, openvpn, pfsense, samba4, freeradius

I've successfully set up Freeradius 3.0.12 with NTLM-Auth against a Samba 4.5.8 AD domain controller. Radtest works fine with every user and a correct password. When I try to authenticate OpenVPN users on pfSense against the Freeradius server, it struggles to find the correct Auth-Type for the user. Freeradius -X yields the following results:

```
(8) Received Access-Request Id 186 from 10.100.0.254:25983 to 10.100.0.32:1812 length 115
(8)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.25
(8)   NAS-Identifier = "openVPN"
(8)   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(8)   NAS-Port = 1194
(8)   Called-Station-Id = "192.168.1.25:1194"
(8)   User-Name = "user@samdom.example.com"
(8)   User-Password = "XXXXXX"
(8) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(8)   authorize {
(8)     policy filter_username {
(8)       if (&User-Name) {
(8)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(8)       if (&User-Name)  {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(8)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(8)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(8)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(8)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(8)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(8)     [preprocess] = ok
(8)     [chap] = noop
(8)     [mschap] = noop
(8)     [digest] = noop
(8) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(8) suffix: Looking up realm "samdom.example.com" for User-Name = "user@samdom.example.com"
(8) suffix: No such realm "samdom.example.com"
(8)     [suffix] = noop
(8) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(8)     [eap] = noop
(8)     [files] = noop
(8)     [expiration] = noop
(8)     [logintime] = noop
(8) pap: WARNING: No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(8) pap: WARNING: Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(8)     [pap] = noop
(8)   } # authorize = ok
(8) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(8) Failed to authenticate the user
(8) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(8) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(8)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(8) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(8) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> user@samdom.example.com
(8) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(8)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(8)     [eap] = noop
(8)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(8)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(8)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(8)       else {
(8)         [noop] = noop
(8)       } # else = noop
(8)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(8)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(8) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
```

I tried with and without the realm in the username, the resulting logs didn't change. The freeradius server is configured as described here: http://deployingradius.com/documents/configuration/active_directory.html

I read that setting the default Auth-Type is a bad idea, because it would break any other forms of authentication. I want to use the server for WiFi authentication as well so I need at least PEAP-MSCHAPv2 to work.

Comment: I found out that it works if I add `DEFAULT     Auth-Type = ntlm_auth` to `mods-config/files/authorize`, I'm gonna use this as long as there are no better solutions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above example you're doing PAP not PEAP.  There's no module which'll automatically set ntlm_auth as the auth type so you need to do it in the policy language, i.e.

```
authorize {
    if (&User-Password) {
        update control {
            Auth-Type := ntlm_auth
        }
    }
    eap
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work using winbind?